# How to install Grub Customizer into lubuntu 12.04

Tags: grub2, lubuntu

I'm having problems installing grub customizer into lubuntu 12.04

I tried the code

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

But it won't install

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

What was the terminal output after typing the install command? copy and paste the output. otherwise simply download the .deb file from the ppa and install it by using

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```